# Am getting Nextjs 14 Apollo Graphql token Error for authorized queries

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, next.js13, next.js14

I have a setup for nextjs 14 using nextjs and Apollo graphql. The issue happens where sometimes the token is not received in time and passed to the apollo instance. Upon refreshing the token is received and everything works. Maybe someone who's run into the same issue? Any assistance is appreciated.

My apollo-wrapper code is

```
'use client';

import { ApolloLink, HttpLink } from '@apollo/client';

import {
  ApolloNextAppProvider,
  NextSSRInMemoryCache,
  NextSSRApolloClient,
  SSRMultipartLink,
} from '@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support/ssr';
import { createUploadLink } from 'apollo-upload-client';

import { onError } from '@apollo/client/link/error';
import { RetryLink } from '@apollo/client/link/retry';

const ApolloWrapper = ({
  token,
  children,
}: {
  token?: any;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) => {
  const httpLink = new createUploadLink({
    uri: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT,
    // headers: {
    //   authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
    // },
  });

  const authLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
    if (token) {
      try {
        operation.setContext(({ headers }: { headers: any }) => ({
          headers: {
            authorization: `Bearer ${token.value}`,
            ...headers,
          },
        }));
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }

    return forward(operation);
  });

  const authHttpLink = ApolloLink.from([
    onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
      if (graphQLErrors) {
        graphQLErrors.forEach(({ message, locations, path }) =>
          console.error(
            `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`
          )
        );
      }
      if (networkError) {
        console.error('[Network error]:', networkError);
      }
    }),
    authLink,
    new RetryLink(),
    typeof window === 'undefined'
      ? ApolloLink.from([
          new SSRMultipartLink({
            stripDefer: false,
            cutoffDelay: 200,
          }),
          httpLink,
        ])
      : httpLink,
  ]);

  const makeClient = () =>
    new NextSSRApolloClient({
      name: 'web-ssr',
      version: '1.2',
      link: authHttpLink,
      cache: new NextSSRInMemoryCache(),
      //connectToDevTools: devTools,
    });

  return (
    <ApolloNextAppProvider makeClient={makeClient}>
      {children}
    </ApolloNextAppProvider>
  );
};

export default ApolloWrapper;
```

This was a hack I found in their Github issues and tried it. It allows passing the token from the root

```
export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const cookieStore = cookies();
  const token = cookieStore.get('agro_token');

  return (
    <html
      lang="en"
      dir="ltr"
      // required this one for next-themes, remove it if you are not using next-theme
      suppressHydrationWarning
    >
      <body
        // to prevent any warning that is caused by third party extensions like Grammarly
        suppressHydrationWarning
        className={cn(inter.variable, lexendDeca.variable, 'font-inter')}
      > 
        <ApolloWrapper token={token}>
          <ThemeProvider>
            <NextProgress />
            {children}
            <Toaster />
            <GlobalDrawer />
            <GlobalModal />
          </ThemeProvider>
        </ApolloWrapper> 
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

The queries will begin working after refreshing the browser as the token seems to have been received in apollo. I've tried delaying and forcing a reload but it does not seem to help much. If i log the token, I can see it's logged correctly. Been stuck on this for a couple days now.